# Trying to write a PHP if/else statement but failing miserably can anyone help me out?

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

So I'm trying to make a if/else statement in PHP, I have the if statement down and it's returning what I want, but I can't seem to figure out the else statement. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<div class="row">
        <?php while($items->have_posts())   : $items->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php 

                    if( get_field('sauce_or_spice') ): ?>
                    <div class="large-4 medium-6 columns">
                        <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                    <a href="https://shop.deadeyebbq.com/password" ?>
                        <div class="thumbnail products">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                        <p><?php the_field('description'); ?></p>
                        <p><?php the_field('price'); ?></p>
                        <a class="video-button">Buy now!</a>
                    </div>
                 <?php elseif( get_field(!('sauce_or_spice')) ): ?>
                 <?php echo'HELLO'; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you **want** the `else` statement to return? Part of a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is describing what **should** happen -- simply stating that something is not working doesn't provide a problem statement.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'm wanting it to just give me a place to return something, I'm going to make a separate div. If I could just have it echo something to see if it's working that's all I need.

Comment: The issue is in you elseif you wrote `!('sauce_or_spice')`... what is not (!) of a string? What you want is `!get_field('sauce_or_spice')`

Comment: I take it you're trying to `echo` out `HELLO`? Just use `elseif(!get_field('sauce_or_spice'))` or a simple `else()` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `<?php elseif( !get_field('sauce_or_spice') ): ?>`

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a gentleman! Also, I was so close to this, I had the ! in front of the 'sauce_or_spice'. DAMN IT! haha

Answer (score 1):

> Your negating condition is wrong. **Correct syntax below**

```
  <?php elseif( !get_field('sauce_or_spice') ): ?>
```

Hope this helps